# IBM MQ change userID when an app is started on remote MQ

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, websphere, ibm-mq

When I deploy my app to remote IBM MQ. Then I see that userID is changed to a user of my pc. I set userID = prod, but see in logs (get logs from a remote MQ), that userID = ps (ps - the user of my pc).
But, if the app is started locally, I don't see this problem.

I use ubuntu, docker, Kubernetes, node.js.
I put userID in code, but might I should config it through Docker?
Or how should the conf be changed to fix this problem?

```
("use strict");
const mq = require("ibmmq");
const fs = require("fs");
const logger = require("../config/logerConfig");
const MQC = mq.MQC;

const StringDecoder = require("string_decoder").StringDecoder;
const decoder = new StringDecoder("utf8");

function ToMQ() {
  const qMgr = "queueManagerName";
  const qName = "queueName";
  const connName = "somehost";

  let queueHandle;

  const cno = new mq.MQCNO();
  const sco = new mq.MQSCO();
  const csp = new mq.MQCSP();
  const cd = new mq.MQCD();
  csp.UserId = "prod";
  csp.Password = "";
  cno.SecurityParms = csp;
  cno.Options |= MQC.MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING;
  cd.ConnectionName = connName;
  cd.ChannelName = "channelName";
  //cd.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
  cd.SSLClientAuth = MQC.MQSCA_OPTIONAL;
  cno.ClientConn = cd;
  cno.SSLConfig = sco;

  mq.setTuningParameters({
    syncMQICompat: true
  });

  mq.Connx(qMgr, cno, function(err, hConn) {
    if (err) {
      logger.errorLogger().error("Failed to connect to MQ!");
    } else {
      logger.serverLogger().info(`Connection successful`);

      const od = new mq.MQOD();
      od.ObjectName = qName;
      od.ObjectType = MQC.MQOT_Q;
      const openOptions = MQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
      mq.Open(hConn, od, openOptions, function(err, hObj) {
        queueHandle = hObj;
        if (err) {
          logger.errorLogger().error(err.message);
        } else {
          getMessages();
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

function formatErr(err) {
  if (err) {
    ok = false;
    return "MQ call failed at " + err.message;
  } else {
    return "MQ call successful";
  }
}

function getMessages() {
  const md = new mq.MQMD();
  const gmo = new mq.MQGMO();

  gmo.Options =
    MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT |
    MQC.MQGMO_MQWI_UNLIMITED |
    MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT |
    MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
  gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;

  gmo.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;

  mq.setTuningParameters({
    getLoopPollTimeMs: 500
  });
  mq.Get(queueHandle, md, gmo, getCB);
}

function getCB(err, hObj, gmo, md, buf, hConn) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.mqrc == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
      logger.serverLogger().info("No more messages available.");
    } else {
      logger.errorLogger().error(formatErr(err.message));
      exitCode = 1;
    }
    ok = false;
    mq.GetDone(hObj);
  } else {
    if (md.Format == "MQSTR") {
      const message = decoder.write(buf);
      const metaJSON = getMetaJson(message);
      try {
        fs.writeFileSync(
          .... process
        );
        logger.serverLogger().info(message);
      } catch (e) {
        logger.errorLogger().error("Cannot write file ", e.message);
      }
    } else {
      logger.serverLogger().info("binary message: " + buf);
    }
    gmo.Options &= ~MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
    gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
  }
}

function getMetaJson(message) {
 // parse JSON
}
```

Comment: Check environment settings in the shell you're using, might be at the C layer that it picks up your global export?

Comment: @oljica 
Thank you for the response.
I newbie in MQ. Could you tell how I need to do it?

Comment: You can not pass a blank password in the csp.

Comment: Setting a user id (and password) in the csp will only have an effect if your queue manager is configured to use these. Is your queue manager set up with Connection Authentication (Issue DISPLAY QMGR CONNAUTH to see in the first instance).

Comment: The queue manager will not validate a blank password.

Comment: You say you're deploying your app to a remote MQ, what do you mean, connecting to, or deploying in same env; where does your app run? In a container?
And MQ server is in another container? As @morag-hugson said, see what the queue manager is checking for when apps are connecting to it;
Depending on config, will check for different things when apps connect in
[Conn auth](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q113250_.htm)

Comment: [LearnMQ tutorial for setting up a developer QM in Docker](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/mq-connect-to-queue-manager/#docker)
This script is used to set up things on the server side [not-for-prod! qm setup example](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-samples/blob/master/gettingStarted/mqsc/mq-dev-config.mqsc) 
then
[App example that passes checks and connects in](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/)

Comment: Output from that QM;

`display chlauth(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)
     4 : display chlauth(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.
   CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   DESCR(Allows connection via APP channel)
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)
   USERSRC(CHANNEL)                        CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)
   ALTDATE(2019-11-21)                     ALTTIME(12.10.48)`

Comment: Some [samples](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns) in other languages that play with that Docker setup